# AWS Firehose data transformation concurrency limits

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a use case in which I have to collect thousands of records per second from different producers and push them to elastic search using AWS firehose. I am also using a data transformation lambda on the firehose which does a fair amount of computation before passing the records back to the firehose.

Firehose is supposed to invoke lambda with each buffered batch asynchronously before the data is buffered again to be delivered to the destination.

I ran a basic test with ingress rate of 4k records per second for 15 minutes and here is how the system responded.

[image: Firehose CloudWatch Metrics]
[Firehose CloudWatch Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PBJ5.jpg)

[image: Lambda CloudWatch Metrics]
[Lambda CloudWatch Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGyDC.jpg)

Looking at the firehose metrics, it is obvious that it took the firehose more than an hour to process all the incoming events. As there isn't any lambda throttles (figure 2), So I am wondering why Firehose didn't run as many lambdas as possible to be able to keep up with the input rate?

As shown in the second figure, I have around 30 lambda invocations per minute and the average processing duration is 8000ms.

So I am wondering if firehose runs lambda concurrently? and is there any firehose-lambda concurrency limits that I am missing?

Comment: Is the lambda running in VPC? I'm asking, because I haven't done lambda-firehose integration so far. If it is, then maybe you don't have enough ENIs in your VPC available?

Comment: No, it's not running in a VPC

Answer (score 1):

Each Lambda eventsource will in principle be associated with 1 Lambda instance. This is to ensure correct ordering of data getting processed.

If you want to increase the throughput at the expense of not having a guarantee that the data will have correct ordering, you can use "InvokeAsync" from inside the lambda function (passing the same arguments). This way you call the lambda a second time, this time asynchronous, which will increase the throughput as expected.

A blog post detailing a similar issue can be found here: https://medium.com/retailmenot-engineering/building-a-high-throughput-data-pipeline-with-kinesis-lambda-and-dynamodb-7d78e992a02d

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I came across this blog post, but calling lambda asynchronously doesn't work with my use-case as I need to push events back to the firehose

Comment: Kinesis streams will have 1 lambda instance per shard, perhaps that might be a way to increase throughput? Otherwise contacting support might be you best option